# Generate Video Thumbnails in Java - Many thumbnail on one image

Tags: image, thumbnails

I want to generate one big image from video with .mp4 format .
A sample like it should look:

[image: sample]
<sub>(source: [mzstatic.com](http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/e1/c6/20/e1c620c1-5167-4be1-a037-516fe2114bd8/screen800x500.jpeg))</sub>

Exist any free example of code in java ?
Any suggestion what library use to do such thing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Xuggler library: http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/

Here are some examples how to capture frames: https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/tree/master/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos